# WP8 Local database overwrite

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am building an app that has a local database preloaded with lots of information. That database is stored on the Assets folder of the application and on the first launch of the application it is getting copied to the isolated storage.

```
class DatabaseHelper : DataContext
{

    private const int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;

    ...

    private void Initialize()
    {

        DatabaseSchemaUpdater dbUpdater;

        if (!DatabaseExists())
        { 

            // Copy over the preloaded database
            CopyDatabase();

            dbUpdater = this.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
            dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion = DATABASE_VERSION;
            dbUpdater.Execute();

        }
        else
        {
            CheckDabaseVersion();
        }

    }

    private void CheckDabaseVersion()
    {

        DatabaseSchemaUpdater dbUpdater;

        dbUpdater = this.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();

        if (dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion < DATABASE_VERSION)
        {

            //Save User Data
            //SaveUserData();

            DeleteDatabase();

            //Copy over the new version of the preloaded database
            CopyDatabase();

            //Update the database version
            dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion = DATABASE_VERSION;
            dbUpdater.Execute();

            this.SubmitChanges();


            //Copy User Data
            //CopyUserData();


        }

    }

    ... 
}
```

When I want to update the data in the database I update the preloaded database with the new data and then increase the `DATABASE_VERSION`. What that should do is on the next launch the app checks and identifies that the database in the isolated storage is not up to date and copies the new one from assets storage. See `CheckDabaseVersion()` above.

The problem with the code above is that after that happens when I try to access any data I get the following error:

```
Operation not allowed after DeleteDatabase call.
```

Any ideas? How can I overwrite the database in the isolated storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to overwrite your database in the isolated storage after you’ve shut down (with `Dispose` call) all instances of DataContext accessing that database.

Here’s the code for your case (untested):

```
class DatabaseHelper: DataContext
{
    internal bool shouldUpgradeDatabase()
    {
        var dbUpdater = this.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
        return dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion < DATABASE_VERSION;
    }

    internal void writeLastVersion()
    {
        var dbUpdater = res.CreateDatabaseSchemaUpdater();
        dbUpdater.DatabaseSchemaVersion = DATABASE_VERSION;
        dbUpdater.Execute();
    }

    static DatabaseHelper initialize()
    {
        DatabaseHelper res = new DatabaseHelper();

        if( !res.DatabaseExists() )
        {
            CopyDatabase();
            res.writeLastVersion();
            return res;
        }

        if( !res.shouldUpgradeDatabase() )
            return res;

        // Should upgrade.
        res.DeleteDatabase();
        res.Dispose();
        res = null;

        CopyDatabase(); //< This should overwrite your files OK, because we've shut down the data context
        res = new DatabaseHelper();
        res.writeLastVersion();
        return res;
    }
}
```